# Groovy Custom Validator

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

Grails 2.2.3

My Custom Validator

```
bankCode( nullable: false, blank: false, minSize: 8, maxSize: 8, validator: {pValue, pDomain ->
        List<CashAccountMapping> lCashAccountMappingList =
            CashAccountMapping.findAllByBankCodeAndSchoolYear(pValue, pDomain.schoolYear )
        lCashAccountMappingList = lCashAccountMappingList - pDomain
        if (lCashAccountMappingList) {
            return 'cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message'
        }
    })
```

My custom error message is not returning as I would have thought. It is somewhere below how do I get out?
I want to get it to a string of all errors to display to the user

```
if ( newCashAccountMapping.validate() ) {
    newCashAccountMapping.save(flush:true)
}
else {
    newCashAccountMapping.errors.each { it
        println it //Add to a string of errors
    }
}
```

In my messages.properties

```
cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message={0} XYZ
```

I get the following when running the code:

> [Field error in object 'com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping' on field 'bankCode': rejected value [CK01 036]; codes [com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode.validator.error.com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode,com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode.validator.error.bankCode,com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode.validator.error.java.lang.String,com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode.validator.error,cashAccountMapping.bankCode.validator.error.com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode,cashAccountMapping.bankCode.validator.error.bankCode,cashAccountMapping.bankCode.validator.error.java.lang.String,cashAccountMapping.bankCode.validator.error,com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode,com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.bankCode,com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.java.lang.String,com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message,cashAccountMapping.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode,cashAccountMapping.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.bankCode,cashAccountMapping.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.java.lang.String,cashAccountMapping.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message,cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.com.srm.ledger.CashAccountMapping.bankCode,cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.bankCode,cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message.java.lang.String,cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message]; arguments [bankCode,Cash Account Mapping,CK01 036]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] does not pass custom validation]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
if (lCashAccountMappingList) {
    return ['cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message']
}
```

Then grails will look for this property:

```
yourClassName.bankCode.cashAccountMapping.invalid.validator.message=Invalid {0} value
```

See the [validator documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.3/ref/Constraints/validator.html) for more examples.